# Chain callback in Dash with same output

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Problem:
Figure still displays old trace burned into graph (Dash 2.7). To fix this I want to return an empty graph and then the updated graph to the same graph component, using callbacks.

A callback can't trigger itself which presents and issue for all my solutions to the problem.

EG.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Output('reset-graph', 'data'),
    Input('reset-graph', 'data'),
    Input('button','n_clicks')
)
def click(reset, button):
    if reset:
        return make_fig(), False
    
    trig = str(ctx.triggered_id)
    if trig == 'button':
        return {}, True
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

This will not work as the callback will not trigger itself.

EDIT: Clarity. Also this was an issue with Dash 2.7

Comment: This is not clear what you are asking. You might want to provide the relevant part of the app layout, and to explain a bit what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your issue, what is your problem with this?

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Input('button','n_clicks')
)
def click(click):
    return make_fig()
```

If for some reason, you want to create an empty figure, then update. You can use a 2nd callback (1st will delete the current figure, the 2nd will create a new one).

It can actually be done in one callback, but for clarity, I think this approach is easier. You need to add the `allow_duplicate=True` in the `graph.figure` Output so it can be updated from a different callback.

The first callback use the button as input, then sets the empty graph and update the contents of a new div `intermediate_step`, that is updated with whatever n_clicks is.

Then, `intermediate_step.children` will be used as an input of another callback that will update `graph.figure` with a new graph.

```
@app.callback( 
    Output('graph', 'figure', allow_duplicate=True),
    Output('intermediate_step', 'children'),
    Input('button','n_clicks')
)
def click(n_clicks):
    return dict(), n_clicks

@app.callback( 
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Input('intermediate_step','children')
)
def new_graph(n_click):
    return make_fig()
```

Comment: How could this be done in one callback? I implemented it with one but it could not return an empty figure, and then trigger itself through 'intermediate_step' equiv to return make_fig() on the second call